# Beautiful Soup find all to find certain div with no class

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the url, date and hyperlink text from each entry in the table in this page: https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/default.aspx

Previously I would have just used the code of

```
r = requests.get("https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/default.aspx")

all = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "the class for this div")
```

Then I would iterate through the "all" list like in the below (for urls).

```
for item in all:
    print(item.find("a")["href"])
```

The problem is that there is no class for the particular div required here so I cannot get a list of this table's values. I know I can leave this class as None but there are other divs in this page that are NA. I tried using elements like in the below but this returns a single item list.

```
all = soup.select("#ctl00_ctl45_g_76f28544_b3c4_43f4_b435_13e7b563f7f1 > div:nth-child(2)")
```

I know I could apply string manipulation on the soup.select() but I feel like this would be bad practice.

What, in your more experienced, opinions is the best approach for this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use `soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': None})` the look to the div without any `class` attribute. However, I do not find in your page the `<href>` you are looking for ?

Comment: Hi, there are many other divs without classes so I do not think this will work :(

Path to the href is: //*[@id="ctl00_ctl45_g_76f28544_b3c4_43f4_b435_13e7b563f7f1"]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/h3/a

I tried your code and it is giving me a UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 20497: character maps to <undefined> :(

Comment: It works. It returns 60 `div` without classes when typing `soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': None})` `print(len(all_div))`

Comment: Yes you are correct, I needed to add .encode("utf-8") to my print statement. I will just update my for loop to skip null findings. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following css selector.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/default.aspx")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select("a[href^='https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages']"):
    print(item['href'])
```

OR

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/default.aspx")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('div.searchfilter-userfilterbox+div a'):
    print(item['href'])
```

**Output**:

```
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Pure-Tassie---Organic-Pure-Apple-juice-ranges.aspx
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Berg-Deli-Prosciutto-Sliced-100g.aspx
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Kimchi-Company-Kimchi-600g-and-300g.aspx
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Pure-Tassie---Apple-and-Blackcurrant-Juice-1.5L.aspx
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Green-Co.-Enoki-Mushrooms-200g and 300g.aspx
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Black-Swan-crafted-basil-dip-with-cashews-and-parmesan-200g.aspx
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Castard-Soboro-Bread-130g.aspx
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Shelby's-chocolate-chip-cookies.aspx
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/The-Loose-Leaf-Lettuce-Company.aspx
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Supreme-Salads-mesculin-salad-mixes.aspx
```

---

Or you can use below regex.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/default.aspx")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile('https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages')):
    print(item['href'])
```

---

If you don't want regex then try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/default.aspx")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find('div',class_='searchfilter-userfilterbox').find_next('div').find_all('a'):
    print(item['href'])
```

---

**Update**:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
r = requests.get("https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/default.aspx")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find('div',class_='searchfilter-userfilterbox').find_next('div').find_all('a'):
    print(item['href'])
    print(item.find_previous('div').text)
    print(item.find_next('td').text)
    print(item.find_next('td').find_next('td').text)
```

**Output**:

```
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Pure-Tassie---Organic-Pure-Apple-juice-ranges.aspx
9/05/2020
Juice Isle Pty Ltd
Due to microbial (mycotoxin - Patulin) contamination
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Berg-Deli-Prosciutto-Sliced-100g.aspx
8/05/2020
ALDI
This recall is due to an incorrect back label resulting in an undeclared milk allergen
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Kimchi-Company-Kimchi-600g-and-300g.aspx
28/04/2020
The Kimchi Company Pty Ltd
Due to Potential microbial contamination due to under-allocation of salt.
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Pure-Tassie---Apple-and-Blackcurrant-Juice-1.5L.aspx
24/04/2020
Juicy Isle Pty Ltd
Due to microbial (mycotoxin patulin) contamination
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Green-Co.-Enoki-Mushrooms-200g and 300g.aspx
14/04/2020
Choi's Mushrooms
The recall is due to microbial (Listeria monocytogenes) contamination
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Black-Swan-crafted-basil-dip-with-cashews-and-parmesan-200g.aspx
3/04/2020
Monde Nissin Australia Pty Ltd (Black Swan Foods)
The recall is due to the presence of an undeclared allergen (peanuts).
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Castard-Soboro-Bread-130g.aspx
1/04/2020
Sejong Global Trading Pty Ltd
Due to  the presence of an undeclared allergen (peanut).
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Shelby's-chocolate-chip-cookies.aspx
27/03/2020
Shelby's Healthy Hedonism/Rousche Group Pty Ltd
The recall is due to the presence of undeclared allergens (hazelnut and cashew)
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/The-Loose-Leaf-Lettuce-Company.aspx
20/03/2020
The Loose Leaf Lettuce Company 
The recall is due to microbial (Salmonella) contamination. 
https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/foodrecalls/recalls/Pages/Supreme-Salads-mesculin-salad-mixes.aspx
20/03/2020
Supreme Salads
Due to microbial (Salmonella) contamination.
```

Comment: Hey, sorry but my problem is not specific to url's I need the other attributes as well i.e. date and description. However, I believe I will be able to rejig your code to do so. Thanks

Comment: @TobiasFunke : Check the updated answer with date and desc.

Comment: Thanks this is the best solution. I did not know about the find_next or find_previous function. Thanks again!